# Sitecore XConnect XdbCollectionUnavailableException Filter and XConnect Exception Filter OnException errors on OData Contacts / DeviceProfiles

Tags: xdb, xconnect

We are using Sitecore 9.3 in our application and we are getting XConnect XdbCollectionUnavailableException Filter on OData Contacts / DeviceProfiles in Sitecore XConnect

Here is the Stack trace from Application Insights:

```
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Sy9nchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
```

I've been looking for what is causing this error for a while now but I can't find any leads, Could anyone please suggest on this?

Comment: Could you please check if your xConnect is working, also check certificates are correct and services are running. –

Comment: Look at this link that might be useful https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0719199

Comment: XConnect Search Indexer Service was not running and after starting this service, it works fine and we did not receive the above error. Thanks @SwatiGupta

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}

Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

Try the above commands in the Windows PowerShell console and restart your system.